# How to solve T(n) = T(0.2*n^0.5) + 1?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I know how to solve `T(n) = T(n^0.5) + 1`. Let `m = lg n` and `S(m) = T(2^m)`. We then get `S(m) = S(m/2) + 1`. And we know `S(m) = Θ(lg m)`. So `T(n) = Θ(lg lg n)`.

However I'm not sure how to solve `T(n) = T(0.2*n^0.5) + 1`. The `0.2` is throwing me off. If I use the same method, I'm not sure how to figure out what `S(m)` is.

Comment: Maybe move this to mathoverflow?

Comment: This might be better over at the CompSci sister site. Or math.se. I can't really see the relevance to programming per se.

Comment: I know it's cheating but [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+T%28n%5E0.5%29+%2B+1) can solve those ;)

Comment: I think you should learn about Masters Theorem and its special cases to solve recursive complexities.

Comment: Sorry if I posted this question on the wrong site. I'll keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the new one, you get

```
S(lg n) = S(lg 0.2 + 0.5 lg n) + 1
S(m) = S(lg 0.2 + 0.5 m) + 1.
```

The trick is to substitute `R(x) = S(m + 2 lg 0.2)`.

```
R(x) = S(m + 2 lg 0.2)
     = S(lg 0.2 + 0.5 (m + 2 lg 0.2)) + 1
     = S(0.5 m + 2 lg 0.2) + 1
     = R(0.5 x) + 1
```

Then unravel the substitutions and conclude that `T(n) = Theta(lg lg n)`, as before.